# Not able to access data lake file in Azure synapse dedicated pool

Tags: sql, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake

I created Azure synapse and data lake inside that
1.I uploaded one parquet file in data lake which is connected to synapse
2.When i access that file in serverless pool using openrowset it works
3.but when i access that file in dedicated sql pool it is not authorized. Please check screenshot and same issue arrise when i call this file spark pool
[image: Please check attached image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an authorization issue: the default credential works fine in the `OPENROWSET` serverless pool, but it does not work in the dedicated pool.

I have tried all available credentials mentioned in this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/copy-into-transact-sql?vi).

|  | CSV | Parquet | ORC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Azure Blob Storage | SAS/MSI/SERVICE PRINCIPAL/KEY/AAD | SAS/KEY | SAS/KEY |
| Azure Data Lake Gen2 | SAS/MSI/SERVICE PRINCIPAL/KEY/AAD | SAS (blob 1 )/MSI (dfs 2 )/SERVICE PRINCIPAL/KEY/AAD | SAS (blob 1 )/MSI (dfs 2 )/SERVICE PRINCIPAL/KEY/AAD |

For ADLS Gen2, you need to provide any one of the above-mentioned credentials.

I recommend using `MSI`. Use the code below and ensure you have the minimum RBAC roles required:

> - Minimum RBAC roles required: Storage Blob Data Contributor or Storage Blob Data Owner for the Azure AD registered SQL Database server

[image]

Comment: Thank you it worked when loading in bulk, but sometime it does not work in openrowset give this error "File 'https://datalaketestingaccess.dfs.core.windows.net/containername/NYCTripSmall.parquet' cannot be opened because it does not exist or it is used by another process." so how can we write so that we can exist and same thing for notebook if i access this file there get this error - TOKEN_PROVIDER_USER_ERROR: Livy session has failed. Session state: Error. Error code: TOKEN_PROVIDER_USER_ERROR. Unable to register the job Source: User.

Comment: If you have any permission to this storage account, then you need to allow that permission like using SAS,account key, managed identity or azure AD user.

Comment: But code in notebook working properly before then why suddenly it gave this problem -TOKEN_PROVIDER_USER_ERROR: Livy session has failed. Session state: Error. Error code: TOKEN_PROVIDER_USER_ERROR. Unable to register the job Source: User.

Comment: did you added or set any configuaration to the spark pool.?

Comment: check with any other spark pool.